# View Controller Not Displaying Details

Tags: ios, iphone, viewcontroller

I have an app here that asks for user input for 3 fields. After the 3 fields are entered, they are displayed in a view controller inside of a custom cell. You can add as many of these events as you like. You can then choose to click on an event cell to display the information in a new view controller about that specific event. For some reason, the details for the events I have entered are not showing up at all. I just get a blank controller screen. I can't seem to figure out why, but I thought I had the code correctly implemented in this controller. Does it have to do with my creation of a new Event object "theEvent"?

Here is some of my code (the full project will be linked below):

Full Project: *Full Project Link Removed*

FinalDetailViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Event;

@interface FinalDetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Event *event;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateTimeLabel;

@end
```

FinalDetailViewController.m

```
#import "FinalDetailViewController.h"
#import "Event.h"

@interface FinalDetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation FinalDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item


- (void)configureView
{
    Event *theEvent = self.event;

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"CCCC, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
    }
    if (theEvent) {
        self.detailLabel.text = theEvent.detail;
        self.locationLabel.text = theEvent.location;
        self.dateTimeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)theEvent.date];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Just noticed the name of your file. When is your "final project" due to your instructor?

Comment: And when I attempt to build your project, I'm seeing errors like "error: Connection "detailLabel" cannot have a prototype object as its destination." You need to point the labels & items inside your prototype cell somewhere other than "Master Event Cell" prototype cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you intended to make the FinalDetailViewController's table be a static table view (since you're making outlets to the labels, which you can only do in a static table). Change the table view to static cells, and it should work.